# How to annotate System Entities in Dialogflow API?

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are using the Dialogflow API to export entities into Dialogflow.

We cannot use the console because we would need to do it for each customer and it is complicated.

We would like to use system entities though but I cannot manage to find how to do that in the documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents?hl=fr#Intent.TrainingPhrase

Thanks for the help !

Comment: [1] Could you please let me know what exactly you are trying  to achieve through annotations of entities? Also could you please confirm whether you are trying to export or import entities?
[2] System Entity are by default predefined , could you please let me know what is your exact need about system entities, I assume that instead of individual customers you are trying to perform some action on a group of customers, could you please let me know what you are exactly trying to do. 
[3] The documentation link you have provided is for intents  not for entities, could you please clarify on this?

Comment: Hi !
In our tool, we need to annotate Training Phrases with system entities in order to extract information such as the time for a request or a location.
For various reasons, we cannot do it in the dialogflow console and need to do it via API. 
That's why we need to export our Training Phrases into Dialogflow with System Entities annotated.
The documentation link I sent is about Training Phrases.

Answer (score 0):

As Per your Requirement, you want to add system entities to your  Training Phrases through the DialogFlow API and export it to the DialogFlow console. You can achieve this by following  the below steps-

1-You have to create an [Intent Json](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#resource:-intent) file where you need to Provide your Intent and in [Training Phrases](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#trainingphrase) you will Provide your Training Phrase texts.

For example - if your training phrase is “I speak french and my  Address is CDA,sec-9”, you have to break the sentence into parts as DialogFlow API does not automatically annotate training Phrases as Dialogflow Console does.

**Do not forget to add Whitespaces after each Text Part.**

```
{
 "displayName": "details",
 "priority": 500000,
 "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
 "trainingPhrases": [
   {
     "name":"",
     "type": "EXAMPLE",
     "parts": [
       {
         "text": "I speak    "
       },
       {
           "text": "French",
           "entityType":"@sys.language",
           "alias": "language",
           "userDefined": "True"

          
       },
       {
           "text" : " and My address is "
       },
       {
           "text" : "CDA,SEc-10",
           "entityType":"@sys.location",
           "alias": "address",
           "userDefined": "True"
       }
     ]
   }
 ],
 "action": "details",
 "messages": [
   {
     "text": {
       "text": [
         "Here are  my details"
       ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

You can add those [system entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities) which are extendable only as per the [doc.](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-system#extend-tp)
After creating the Json file Use the below Command to export intent with training Phrases to DialogFlow console via DialogFlow API.

**Note:** You need to add your project id in **<**project-id**>** field.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @intent.json \
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<project-id>/agent/intents?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```